# NSTableView Cell with Identifier keep giving nil

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3, nstableview, nstableviewcell

I am working on building MacOS app. I am trying to make table view that updates the cell when I press add button.

[image]

Following is my code:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    let identifier = tableColumn?.identifier as NSString?
    if ( identifier == "NameCell")
    {
        var result: NSTableCellView
        let cell = tableView.make(withIdentifier: "NameCell", owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
        cell.textField?.stringValue = self.data[row].setting!
            return cell

    }
    else if (identifier == "SettingCell")
    {
        if let cell = tableView.make(withIdentifier: "SettingCell", owner: self) as? NSTableCellView {
        cell.textField?.stringValue = self.data[row].setting!
        return cell
    }
    }
    return nil
}
```

However, the line             let cell = tableView.make(withIdentifier: "NameCell", owner: self) as! NSTableCellView is keep failing because it returns nil

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

NameCell is from 
[image]
Can anyone please help me find a way to solve this problem?

Comment: I think identifier I should give is correspond to NSTableColumn not NSTableCellView

Comment: Yes, I think those Identifier should be the identifier of NSTableColumn. Can you please explain how to make sure tableView is not nil (Watch the outlet)?

Comment: Did you change the identifier of both the column and the cell view?

Answer (score 11):

For anyone else who comes here with this same question when trying to make an `NSTableView` fully programmatically: [`makeView(withIdentifier:owner:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1535482-makeview) WILL return `nil` unless a corresponding NIB exists for the given identifier:

> **`NSTableView` documentation:**
>
> If a view with the specified identifier can’t be instantiated from the nib file or found in the reuse queue, this method returns `nil`.

Likewise, the 'owner' param is a NIB-specific concept. In short: you cannot use this method if populating your `NSTableView` with cells programmatically.

In this answer, I detail the Swift code to produce an `NSTableCellView` programmatically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51736468/5951226

However, if you don't want all the features of an `NSTableViewCell`, note that you can return *any* `NSView` in [`tableView(_:viewFor:row:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableviewdelegate/1527449-tableview). So you could, as per the [CocoaProgrammaticHowtoCollection](https://github.com/eonil/CocoaProgrammaticHowtoCollection/blob/6dfad6c9f2fc059ce9cbe7dedbbea00304871fb2/ComponentUsages/NSTableViewExample/main.swift#L44), simply write:

```
let cell = NSTextField()
cell.identifier = "my_id" // Essential! Allows re-use of the instance.
// ... Set any properties you want on the NSTextField.
return cell
```

Comment: The quote from the docs also says "or found in the reuse queue, this method returns nil." - so it should also work without a nib file - right?

Comment: @ChristianKienle I believe you would only be able to get an instance into the reuse queue in the first place by originally having instantiated a view from a nib. Maybe there is a way to do it entirely programmatically, but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: I also think that your assumption is 100% on point and this is also what I observe. But from reading the docs I think the method is just buggy... Because the table view has all the information it needs to actually properly re-use the cells. but it does not.

Answer (score 5):

You should set the "Identifier" with "NameCell" in the NSTableCellView. And your codes should simplified as follow since the column's identifier won't change for ever:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    var result: NSTableCellView
    let cell = tableView.make(withIdentifier: "NameCell", owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
    cell.textField?.stringValue = self.data[row].setting!

    return cell
}
```

references settings in XCode Interface Builder:
[image]

Comment: Worked for me, but I had to use `make(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "NameCell"), owner: self)`